# Why does UITextFiled with Secure Text Entry crash when pasting in long string (iOS10)

Tags: ios, swift

This seems to only affect apps running on iOS 10. Both on devices and in the simulator. There is no exception thrown, but the CPU load jumps to 100% and memory runs up until the app gets killed. Still trying to isolate the issue and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why downvote the question? This is an actual bug and it's important to try and document it for others.

Comment: I'm okay with it, but since it's not strictly a code question, others may have issues. But I think documenting solutions like this on SO is fine.

Comment: Your question is being down voted and closed because you have not provided any useful details. Update your question with relevant code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: This issue is entirely abstracted away from code. It's a stock UIKit object exhibiting a bug at runtime. Using the Interface Builder in a new project, one could reproduce this without writing a single line of code. But it's still an issue that can be, and IS solved with code.

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to write up some defect to the ios/swift folks to document that bug? And to get it fixed? Instead of putting it up here?

Comment: Filing a bug report with Apple is not the same as reaching out to the community for help with an immediate solution. We all work with frameworks and libraries that have bugs. I would say the entire community relies on SO to keep up with issues and solutions/workarounds related to developing on various platforms. The volume is staggering, and no system Apple has can resolve things in real time. Some framework/os bugs get fixed, some persist for years. Meanwhile we have code to ship.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a genuine iOS10 bug, but it's only caused when the text field has it's 'adjust to fit' property enabled. So far the only fix I found is to disable it.

```
passwordTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
```

Comment: Wow, this solved this weird bug that would increase the memory so much and CPU.

Comment: For me I had txtPassword.secureTextEntry = YES; And when the user input a password more than 13 characters the app would freeze and be at above state. Disable adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth for inserting secureTextEntry fixed this issue.

Comment: Just an add-on - if the issue still persist then save password value in variable and then clear the textfield value before calling next controller/interactor.